# What is wrong with my postgresql query and why am I not getting the right calculation

Tags: postgresql

so essentially I have a database/table with lots of students id's and their respective scores across multiple exams. What I am trying to do is make a mathematical function in my query so that I just a display of the **Percent Change** from one exam to the next for whichever two exams I choose.
this is my query and it does return a result, but not what I want:

```
SELECT ("2019-2020 NWEA Reading Fall Test Percentile" - "2018-2019 NWEA Reading Spring Test Percentile") / "2018-2019 NWEA Reading Spring Test Percentile" * 100 AS "percentage_change" FROM ppn_practice;
```

The two problems I'm facing is that the values that I am getting are not correct and I suspect it is because the final table I am getting that has a column named "percentage_change", and it is an INTEGER data type. I need to know how to make it NUMERIC.

thank you

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: You can't just do straight math expressions in SQL, you have to use [math functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html).

Comment: @selfagency, that is not true: `select  ((10 - 5)/ 2.0) * 100 ;  250.00`.

Comment: Postgres does integer division unless one of the values is float or numeric. So I'm guessing the numerator and the denominator are both integers. Cast one of them to numeric e.g. "2018-2019 NWEA Reading Spring Test Percentile"::numeric

Comment: It works for generating a static value but I don't believe you can refer to the value of a table cell in a mathematical expression without a math function.

Comment: @Adrian what is `"2019-2020 NWEA Reading Fall Test Percentile"` here? is that a column name of table `ppn_practice`? It would be better if you have provided sample of your table too

Comment: @selfagency. Sure you can: `select pot_ct/qty AS cell_per from projection where qty > 0 order by random() limit 1; 18.00`.

Comment: @devReddit. This is not my question, you need to address Inan Khan. Though from the query I would assume it is a column name.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your respective column names are `col1` and `col2` in table `ppn_practice` and the corresponding data type of these columns are numeric, your issue shouldn't arise. This query will give you exactly what you want:

```
SELECT (col1- col2) / col3 * 100 AS "percentage_change" FROM ppn_practice;
```

Please crosscheck the data type of the columns you've used and whether the column names are okay, by doing some simpler queries with the column names.

Comment: thank you for the help, you are correct, I also found out I need to add "numeric(10,2)" in order to avoid getting the super long values I was getting before that was confusing me.

Comment: No all you needed to do is add `round(<your_percent_calc>, 2)`.

Comment: @InanKhan,  if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.